# Replacing a text field in a document using regular expression c#

Tags: c#, regex

I got a simple c# code that can Replace Fields like First name, Middle Name, Last Name in a word document I used Microsoft office object library but I just now found out that Windows word is not allowed in the system so I need to read the Doc File and use a regular expression to Replace the Fields

Ex:
I [FirstName] [LastName], Son of [Fathers Name] & [Mothers Name] From [city]. Address [First Name],[Address Line 1]

Now there are going to be eight such templates and need to replace the details FirstName(ex: John) in place of [First Name] LastName(ex: Doe) in place of [LastName] if the middle name is not given then remove the [MiddleName] and create new doc file. These fields may be repeated n number of times can someone please give me an example of how to do this or is regular expression necessary for this(at least 20 such fields in each template ) if I use Find and Replace it is too much of unnecessary code Am I right?

Thank You in Advance

Comment: if you create a methode for Find and replace. and just call the methodes you wopnt have code duplication.

Comment: *I got a simple c# code that ...* Use it.

Comment: We haven't got a chance to answer, you don't show any code you have tried. Show the code, examples of input and expected output.

Comment: @Cid As I mentioned in my Post the system doesn't have MS Office installed

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look to the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/getting-started).
You can directly access to the underlying XML of the docx and you don't need Office installed.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-open-and-add-text-to-a-word-processing-document) example might also help you.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks.